# Dashboard widget: how to bind a list to a non-web XML datasource

Tags: widget, datasource, external, dashboard, dashcode

I have an XML file located on my desktop that I would like to bind to a dashboard widget list (tableview). Although I am able to bind this file if it's within the widget's bundle folder, I am unable to bind the XML file to the list externally. A modal dialog warning shows: "try entering a path relative to your application"--yet this also does not seem to work. And yes, I made sure to check the "Allow external file access" within the Widget Attributes panel.

Answer (score 0):

I think I have found a solution: instead of using the conventional unix file path for the datasource reference, e.g. '/Desktop/myXMLFile.xml', I find that an XML file also has a URL path: 'file:///~/Desktop/myXMLFile.xml'. Coming from the world of Cocoa programming, I was ignorant of XML files and widget behavior as a web 2.0 kind-of-thing.